# Some Wi-Fi connections are very slow, but internet is good

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dual-boot, broadcom

I use dual-boot between Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. Everything runs smooth except one problem: The Wi-Fi doesn't always work well.

I can connect with different Wi-Fi networks, but some networks are very slow (13MB/s) and my browser says I'm not connected to the Internet.

When I ping an IP adress, it responds very fast. I have a broadcom BCM3413. I already updated the drivers. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: 13MB/s is considered quite fast. (13312KB/s???)

Secondly follow carefully and fully [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) answer.